# Server home is not valid for ColdFusion10 in CF Builder

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusionbuilder

Today when I was trying to configure my ColdFusion10 Server with the ColdFusion Builder 2, It shown me a error message like "Sever home is not valid", Screenshot:

[image]

I can not move forward both the "Next" and "Finish" button is disabled and showing the error message.

Can anyone please suggest me which path I should provide ?

Comment: What value did you use for "Application Server" on the previous page?

Comment: @AdamCameron : I have specified "Jrun" as the application server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your comment above: you've selected "JRun" as your application server, but ColdFusion 10 runs on Tomcat. That'll be your problem.